# Speed up VBA code which compares parts of strings in multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

Below code takes more than one hours to complete if sheet contains 2000 rows. I am unable to convert in array. I think if I can convert this into array will be much faster.

```
Sub CompareAndCopy()

Dim NumberOfValues, NumberOfValues2 As Integer
Dim value1, value2 As String
Dim value3 As Long
Dim i, n, j As Long

j = 2

Sheet1.Activate
NumberOfValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").End(xlDown).Row
NumberOfValues2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 1 To NumberOfValues
    value3 = 0
    For n = 1 To NumberOfValues2`enter code here`
        value1 = LCase(Range("A" & n).Value)
        value2 = LCase(Range("M" & i).Value)
        If Mid(value1, 1, Len(value2)) = value2 Then
            value3 = value3 + Range("C" & n).Value
            Range("T" & i).Value = value3
        End If
        Sheet1.Activate
        j = j + 1
    Next
Sheet1.Activate
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First: Why do you activate the sheet within the loop? Maybe this is one of the performance problems?

Comment: Avoid using `Activate` in your code, turn off screen updating (`.ScreenUpdating = False`), What is `j` for?

Comment: See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx perhaps for how to do this using an array.

Comment: You should read `value2` *before* entering the `n` loop.  Likewsie `Range("T" & i).Value = value3` can move to after the `n` loop is done

Answer (score 0):

Include
`Application.Calculation = xlManual` before the loops, and
`Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` after the loops.
And as others suggested, remove those those useless `Activate`.

Comment: Yes above code finished in 1 minute.

Thank you very much patrick. Just for my knowledge , if i have to do using array how this could be ? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Patrick  for code "If Mid(value1, 1, Len(value2)) = value2" i would like add one more condition  where year of column D is equal to 2022. Column D has date in format 01/14/2022. any idea how can i achieve this ?

Comment: use `and year(range("d" & whatever))  = 2022`

Comment: pls mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I am getting type mismatch error for code " If Mid(value1, 1, Len(value2)) = value2 And Year(Range("E" & n).Value) = 2022 "  and how do i marl answerer as accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct code would be ?

```
Sub CompareAndCopy()

Dim NumberOfValues, NumberOfValues2 As Integer
Dim value1, value2 As String
Dim value3 As Long
Dim i, n, j As Long

NumberOfValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").End(xlDown).Row
NumberOfValues2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Application.Calculation = xlManual
For i = 1 To NumberOfValues
    value3 = 0
    'Application.Calculation = xlManual
    For n = 1 To NumberOfValues2`enter code here`
        value1 = LCase(Range("A" & n).Value)
        value2 = LCase(Range("M" & i).Value)
        If Mid(value1, 1, Len(value2)) = value2 Then
            value3 = value3 + Range("C" & n).Value
            Range("T" & i).Value = value3
        End If
      
    Next
    'Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Next
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited your code to comment the unnecessary lines. It's nice to have them during debug period, but afterwards, just mark them as comments.